# How to get proper chunks while requesting table data from database via Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently Pandas have chunk size to speed up processing huge amount of data from database.

What I want to do is, ensure that set of column values should be in same chunk for analysis.

*Due to performance issues I cannot fetch them at once. Any answer based on fetch once with high performance is also welcome.*

Example:

```
col1   col2
1      a      
2      a
3      a
4      b
2      b
1      b
3      b      
5      c
2      c
3      c
```

I want to have meaningful chunks based on `col2`

```
Chunk1:            Chunk2:
col1   col2        col1   col2
1      a           5      c
2      a           2      c
3      a           3      c
4      b
2      b
1      b
3      b
```

If I specify chunk as 5 it will distinguish into 2 chunks, `b` value of `col2` will split from the middle and I cannot do calculations for the col2.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the chunks one by one, store them in a list and then use: pd.concat() for combining them properly:

```
pd.concat([df_chunk1, df_chunk2, ...]
```

it also has a axis parameter, so you could use `axis=1` to specify where the chunk is atatched to, columns or rows.